# Azure Data Factory specify custom output filename when copying to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently using ADF to copy files from an SFTP server to Blob Storage on a scheduled basis.

The filename structure is AAAAAA_BBBBBB_CCCCCC.txt.

Is it possible to rename the file before copying to Blob Storage so that I end up with a folder-like structure like below?

AAAAAA/BBBBBB/CCCCCC.txt

Answer (score 16):

Here is what worked for me

I created 3 parameters in my Blob storage dataset, see the image bellow:
[image: screenshot of my parameters]

I specified the name of my file, added the file extension, you can add anything in the Timestamp just so you could bypass the ADF requirement since a parameter can't be empty.

Next, click on the Connection tab and add the following code in the FileName box: @concat(dataset().FileName,dataset().Timestamp,dataset().FileExtension). This code basically concatenate all parameters do you could have something like "FileName_Timestamp_FileExtension. See the image bellow:

[image: Blob dataset connection tab]

Next, click on your pipeline then select your copy data activity. Click on the Sink tab. Find the parameter Timestamp under Dataset properties and add this code: @pipeline().TriggerTime. See the image bellow:

[image: copy data activity]

Finally, publish your pipeline and run/debug it. If it worked for me then I am sure it will work for you as well :)

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful!

Comment: Solved my problem, Thanks

Comment: I need to add Filename dynamic value here in dataset property - @item().name

Answer (score 0):

With ADF V2, you could do that. First, use a [lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to get all the filenames of your source. 
Then chain a [foreach activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) to iterate the source file names. The foreach activity contains a copy activity. Both your source dataset and sink dataset of the cop activity have parameters for filename and folder path.
You could use [split and replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#split) functions to generate the sink folder path and filename based on your source file names.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the filenames in a GetMetadata-Activity. You can use this as a parameter in a copy-Activity and rename the filenames.

As mentioned in previous answer you can use a replace function to do this:

```
{
    "name": "TgtBooksBlob",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "Destination-BlobStorage-data",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "Target"
        },
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "typeProperties": {
            "fileName": {
                "value": "@replace(item().name, '_', '\\')",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "folderPath": "data"
       }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```