# Azure Data Factory Copy Data - File Renaming Multiple Files

Tags: azure, copy, file-rename, azure-data-factory

Hello to all you brilliant people, I am new to Azure Data Factory and am attempting to create a pipeline that will copy multiple files to a SFTP destination. I have gone through various articles here and other places but haven't found a solution that I have been able to modify to fit my purpose. I have the pipeline working to copy files without issue, however I need to expand this to copy multiple files with its original output name from my Azure Storage (already connected) to the SFTP server with a new file names.

For example: Original Name would be something like DataExtract20211118 and New name would be PPP.AAA01.TSTCCC1.Data.DYYMMDD for one file, and another file would be LayoutExtract20211118 to new name PPP.AAA01.TSTCCC1.Layout.DYYMMDD

I have referenced the following post(s) to get more insight which has helped, but haven't been able to modify the steps to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

[Azure Data Factory specify custom output filename when copying to Blob Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938884/azure-data-factory-specify-custom-output-filename-when-copying-to-blob-storage)

[Copy activity with simultaneous renaming of a file. From blob to blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67801659/copy-activity-with-simultaneous-renaming-of-a-file-from-blob-to-blob/67814779#67814779)
(This one I have been trying to replicate, however, my issue is that when working on the MetaData activity, the option for Field List "Child Items" is not available for me and have been unsuccessful in working around it.)

If anyone is able to help me get a better understanding of what needs to be done to achieve this goal, it would be greatly appreciated, if there are any additional questions or information, please let me know, I am happy to provide whatever I can. I look forward to your responses.

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet of your Get Metadata settings?

Answer (score 0):

In the source dataset, if you select the file name and use the dataset in the `Get Metadata` activity then you will not see the “**child items**” under the Filed list **Arguments**.

[image]

[image]

To get the **child items**, you need to select the folder and leave the filename blank or create a dataset parameter to pass the file name in the source dataset from the `Get Metadata` activity.

You can mention **(*)** in the dataset parameter in the `Get Metadata` activity if you want to pull all files from the folder or you may also select the required type of files.

[image]

[image]

The output of the `Get Metadata` activity gives the list of file names from the folder as shown below.

[image]

You can pass this to the `ForEach` activity and copy the file with the required filename in **Sink** by creating sink filename **dynamically** as mentioned in the reference link you provided in the question.

Comment: Thank you NiharikaMoola-MT, your explanation is very helpful and I really appreciate your time in answering it, I am going to spend some time today testing this out further with your suggestions and see what happens. If I might be so bold to ask, would you have any suggestions on renaming the file if the source is DataExtract20211118.csv it will rename the file to PPP.AAA01.TSTCCC1.Data.DYYMMDD.csv. or I guess if the source file name meets certain conditions, it renames it to the new format. if that makes sense. I suppose I can open a new request for that as It might exceed this topic. Thanks!